# how to resolve this error : Length of feature_names, 2983 does not match number of features, 6

Tags: jupyter-notebook, classification, random-forest

iam a freshener in coding.
i want to visualize `random forest` using grapihcz and got an error like in title. i can't find how to define the feature name and class_names for my data. actually my data is .csv . if i visualize the data will be like this :
[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt2Fw.png)

```
estimator = best_rf.estimators_[5]
```

```
export_graphviz(estimator, out_file='tree.dot', 
                feature_names = y_train,
                class_names = X_train,
                rounded = True, proportion = False, 
                precision = 2, filled = True)
```

i expect the visual of random forest model will be like this :
[random forest tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wktMu.png)
can you guys please help me to define the code for my problem ?

Comment: i try to searching ini another question, but the answer dosnt have a complete code, and i stuck to understanding it